# Using generics to solve a REST scenario

Tags: c#, .net, rest, generics, restsharp

OK. I'm communicating with a REST-based API that returns XML-formatted response. I'm using RESTSharp to make life easier. RESTSharp has a handy feature of creating/populating .NET objects from returned XML if I call `RestClient.Execute<T>()` overload. All of the calls of my API are of the following form:

REQUEST:

```
<GetContactsRequest>                               <--
```

RESPONSE:

```
<GetContactsResponse>                              <--
    <Result>Success</Result>
    <Contacts>...</Contacts>                       <--
</GetContactsResponse>                             <--
```

The nodes that I have highlighted will change depending upon the request. This seems to create a problem for RESTSharp, which uses node names to find corresponding class/property. Earlier, while I was working on another API that always returned the same root level node in all responses, I was able to create a generic class like this:

```
class Response<T>
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public T Data{get; set;}
}
```

which I could then use with all of the API requests. This class doesn't get populated in this new API obviously because the root node name is not `Response`. Do I need to create one class for each request/response, or is there a better solution?